# How to get values of shape key with foreach_get?

Tags: python, scripting

I heard that using `foreach_get` is faster to get the values than using the normal way.

So I tried to get an array of shapekey values using the following method.

I selected the object that has the shapekey and ran it.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

ob = context.object
me = ob.data
sks = me.shape_keys

if sks:
    vals = []
    list = sks.key_blocks.foreach_get("value", vals)
    print(list)
```

However, Console just shows "None" and no values are retrieved.

How can I get the values correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach_get` fills the provided array with the values. It doesn't return anything. The array you pass needs to be the right length too.

```py
    vals = [0.0] * len(sks.key_blocks)
    sks.key_blocks.foreach_get("value", vals)
    print(vals)
```